# TextView NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using ***textHeading named TextView*** in **UploadActivity.java** and ***controlling visibility of button*** in **LoginActivity.java** but getting **Null POinter Exception**

**Line of NPE:**

```
if(UploadActivity.textHeading.getText().equals("0"))
```

**UploadActivity.java:-**

```
    static TextView textHeading = null ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    textHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventNameDate);
    textHeading.setText(CameraLauncherActivity.folder);

    }   
}
```

**LoginActivity.java:-**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            if(UploadActivity.textHeading.getText().equals("0"))
            {
                btnGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                btnGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use static .

Instead use intent and pass the value to `LoginActivity`.

If you want to maintain global state you can use Application class.

Comment: but i just want to check value for textHeading, no matter i went to UploadActivity or not..

Comment: @AbrahimNeil when do you navigate to `UploadActivity`?. If you don't then textview is not initialized and you get NPE

Comment: @AbrahimNeil then how do you expect the textview to be not null??

Comment: any way to control this, but the flow is first user will get LoginActivity then UploadActivity

Comment: @AbrahimNeil you need to reconsider you design

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is giving you NullPointerException because you have not defined `textHeading` anywhere in `LoginActivity`.

Secondly, you can't use `textHeading` in `LoginActivity` because this textview is in XML file that you have defined for `UplaodActivity`. So you can only get `textHeading` in `UploadActivity`. Using same instance in another activity won't help, because, first of all, it is from XML file defined from another activity.

For example, if you do

```
textHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventNameDate);
```

in `LoginActivity` still it'll give you **NPE**. You'll have to pass data through intent.

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting LoginActivity from UploadActivity in that intent put value of textHeading like
    intent.putExtra("textHeading", textHeading.getText().toString());
And in UploadActivity's onCreate() get that value and then from that value decide wether you need to make 'btnGallery' Visible or Gone.